# Installing Qutip in fedora 24

Tags: python, fedora, qutip

I can't install Qutip in my fedora 24

```
pip install qutip
```

Whenever I type this , error message showing [It starts like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8g3z.png)  
But at the end [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q54nr.png) happens , and Qutip is not get installed . 
What to do ?

Comment: http://superuser.com

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite evident:

```
gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-001: No such file or directory
```

Somehow this file has vanished from your computer. Find out which package provides this file.

```
sudo dnf provides /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1
Last metadata expiration check: 6 days, 22:14:34 ago on Thu Jul 28 11:58:37 2016.
redhat-rpm-config-40-2.fc24.noarch : Red Hat specific rpm configuration files
Repo        : @System

redhat-rpm-config-40-2.fc24.noarch : Red Hat specific rpm configuration files
Repo        : fedora
```

Then reinstall the package:

```
sudo dnf reinstall -y redhat-rpm-config
```